# VuePress - Algolia increase results

Tags: vue.js, config, algolia, vuepress

Using VuePress with Algolia quick search box.

I could not find in the documentation for Algolia how to increase the number of results shown in the dropdown list. It currently defaults to 5.

Just adding 'hitsPerPage: 10' to the algolia options in the config.js is ignored.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After an email with Algolia support they solved this.

You need to add 'algoliaOptions' with the 'hitsPerPage: 10'

```
algolia: {
   apiKey: 'your key',
   appId: 'your app id',
   indexName: 'your index name',
   algoliaOptions: {
     hitsPerPage: 10,
   },
```

Answer (score 1):

I've recommendded to use native vuepress SearchBox instead of Algolia.
So, you must to copy vuepress theme by command `vuepress eject [targetDir]` (https://vuepress.vuejs.org/default-theme-config/#ejecting). This command will create copy of vuepress theme directory that you could be changing.

Go to theme directory, in "components" folder create a new file "SearchBox.vue" with the following code:

```
    <template>
      <div class="search-box">
        <input
          @input="query = $event.target.value"
          aria-label="Search"
          :value="query"
          :class="{ 'focused': focused }"
          autocomplete="off"
          spellcheck="false"
          @focus="focused = true"
          @blur="focused = false"
          @keyup.enter="go(focusIndex)"
          @keyup.up="onUp"
          @keyup.down="onDown"
        >
        <ul
          class="suggestions"
          v-if="showSuggestions"
          :class="{ 'align-right': alignRight }"
          @mouseleave="unfocus"
        >
          <li
            class="suggestion"
            v-for="(s, i) in suggestions"
            :class="{ focused: i === focusIndex }"
            @mousedown="go(i)"
            @mouseenter="focus(i)"
          >
            <a :href="s.path" @click.prevent>
              <span class="page-title">{{ s.title || s.path }}</span>
              <span v-if="s.header" class="header">&gt; {{ s.header.title }}</span>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </template>

    <script>
    /* global SEARCH_MAX_SUGGESTIONS, SEARCH_PATHS */
    export default {
      data () {
        return {
          query: '',
          focused: false,
          focusIndex: 0
        }
      },

      computed: {
        showSuggestions () {
          return (
            this.focused
            && this.suggestions
            && this.suggestions.length
          )
        },

        suggestions () {
          const query = this.query.trim().toLowerCase()
          console.log(this.query)
          if (!query) {
            return
          }

          const { pages } = this.$site
          // const max = SEARCH_MAX_SUGGESTIONS
          const max = this.$site.themeConfig.searchMaxSuggestions || 5

          const localePath = this.$localePath
          const matches = item => (
            item.title
            && item.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(query) > -1
          )
          const res = []
          for (let i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
            if (res.length >= max) break
            const p = pages[i]
            // filter out results that do not match current locale
            if (this.getPageLocalePath(p) !== localePath) {
              continue
            }

            // filter out results that do not match searchable paths
            if (!this.isSearchable(p)) {
              continue
            }

            if (matches(p)) {
              res.push(p)
            } else if (p.headers) {
              for (let j = 0; j < p.headers.length; j++) {
                if (res.length >= max) break
                const h = p.headers[j]
                if (matches(h)) {
                  res.push(Object.assign({}, p, {
                    path: p.path + '#' + h.slug,
                    header: h
                  }))
                }
              }
            }
          }
          return res
        },

        // make suggestions align right when there are not enough items
        alignRight () {
          const navCount = (this.$site.themeConfig.nav || []).length
          const repo = this.$site.repo ? 1 : 0
          return navCount + repo <= 2
        }
      },

      methods: {
        getPageLocalePath (page) {
          for (const localePath in this.$site.locales || {}) {
            if (localePath !== '/' && page.path.indexOf(localePath) === 0) {
              return localePath
            }
          }
          return '/'
        },

        isSearchable (page) {
          let searchPaths = SEARCH_PATHS

          // all paths searchables
          if (searchPaths === null) { return true }

          searchPaths = Array.isArray(searchPaths) ? searchPaths : new Array(searchPaths)

          return searchPaths.filter(path => {
            return page.path.match(path)
          }).length > 0
        },

        onUp () {
          if (this.showSuggestions) {
            if (this.focusIndex > 0) {
              this.focusIndex--
            } else {
              this.focusIndex = this.suggestions.length - 1
            }
          }
        },

        onDown () {
          if (this.showSuggestions) {
            if (this.focusIndex < this.suggestions.length - 1) {
              this.focusIndex++
            } else {
              this.focusIndex = 0
            }
          }
        },

        go (i) {
          if (!this.showSuggestions) {
            return
          }
          this.$router.push(this.suggestions[i].path)
          this.query = ''
          this.focusIndex = 0
        },

        focus (i) {
          this.focusIndex = i
        },

        unfocus () {
          this.focusIndex = -1
        }
      }
    }
    </script>

    <style lang="stylus">
    .search-box
      display inline-block
      position relative
      margin-right 1rem
      input
        cursor text
        width 10rem
        height: 2rem
        color lighten($textColor, 25%)
        display inline-block
        border 1px solid darken($borderColor, 10%)
        border-radius 2rem
        font-size 0.9rem
        line-height 2rem
        padding 0 0.5rem 0 2rem
        outline none
        transition all .2s ease
        background #fff url(search.svg) 0.6rem 0.5rem no-repeat
        background-size 1rem
        &:focus
          cursor auto
          border-color $accentColor
      .suggestions
        background #fff
        width 20rem
        position absolute
        top 1.5rem
        border 1px solid darken($borderColor, 10%)
        border-radius 6px
        padding 0.4rem
        list-style-type none
        &.align-right
          right 0
      .suggestion
        line-height 1.4
        padding 0.4rem 0.6rem
        border-radius 4px
        cursor pointer
        a
          white-space normal
          color lighten($textColor, 35%)
          .page-title
            font-weight 600
          .header
            font-size 0.9em
            margin-left 0.25em
        &.focused
          background-color #f3f4f5
          a
            color $accentColor

    @media (max-width: $MQNarrow)
      .search-box
        input
          cursor pointer
          width 0
          border-color transparent
          position relative
          &:focus
            cursor text
            left 0
            width 10rem

    // Match IE11
    @media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none)
      .search-box input
        height 2rem

    @media (max-width: $MQNarrow) and (min-width: $MQMobile)
      .search-box
        .suggestions
          left 0

    @media (max-width: $MQMobile)
      .search-box
        margin-right 0
        input
          left 1rem
        .suggestions
          right 0

    @media (max-width: $MQMobileNarrow)
      .search-box
        .suggestions
          width calc(100vw - 4rem)
        input:focus
          width 8rem
    </style>
```

Now, the SearchBox works as expected
(https://vuepress.vuejs.org/default-theme-config/#search-box)

If you need to use only AlgoliaSearch, then in theme/components folder that you has been created, open the "AlgoliaSearchBox.vue" file. Find by:

```
    algoliaOptions: Object.assign({
        'facetFilters': [`lang:${lang}`].concat(algoliaOptions.facetFilters || [])
    }, algoliaOptions)
```

And overwrite it using:

```
    algoliaOptions: Object.assign({
        'hitsPerPage': 10,
        'facetFilters': [`lang:${lang}`].concat(algoliaOptions.facetFilters || [])
    }, algoliaOptions)
```

Comment: I'm sorry for my language